# Cannot find name 'environment'. in angular 7

Tags: angular, firebase, compiler-errors, environment

**cannot find environment path ,but there is environment.ts file inside of environment file help me to fix this**  i tried to add manually environment.ts file into the project but it also didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

*i have discovered the error 
 - you need to select environment from auto generating prompt provide by the code editor(i recommend vs code )
 - then it will popup another error for that one you have to give the link to environment as this **environments/environment***